# JQ: Bigint Numbers precision

Tags: json, jq

I have actually a situation were i run into the BIGINT Problem and the haziness with that in jq 1.5/1.6 (in a Windows enviroment).
I read the issue reports and thought that if i transform the number to a string, i can handle that. But i test it with a specific command and the result is the same

```
[. | { last_update: .starbase_detailed_scan.last_update_time, user_name: .starbase_detailed_scan.owner_name, alliance_id: .starbase_detailed_scan.owner_alliance_id | tostring, drydocks: .starbase_detailed_scan.num_drydocks, tier: .starbase_detailed_scan.owner_level, defence_plattform: .starbase_detailed_scan.num_defence_platforms, shield_triggered: .starbase_detailed_scan.player_shield.triggered_on, shield_end: .starbase_detailed_scan.player_shield.expiry_time, parsteel: .starbase_detailed_scan.resources["2325683920"], tritanium: .starbase_detailed_scan.resources["743985951"], dilithium: .starbase_detailed_scan.resources["2614028847"], user_id: .starbase_detailed_scan.owner_user_id, defence_rating: .starbase_detailed_scan.defense_rating }]
```

result:

```
[{"last_update":"2018-12-23T19:26:24","user_name":"Hamita40","alliance_id":"774615702811599900","drydocks":3,"tier":19,"defence_plattform":3,"shield_triggered":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","shield_end":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","parsteel":183649,"tritanium":22459,"dilithium":7074,"user_id":"a2588903decc455283c88508f6a7fedf","defence_rating":25200}]
```

The `Alliance_id` is not correct. The correct id is:

```
774615702811599864
```

Is there any Workaround?

BR
Timo

Answer (score 5):

Using `tostring` is not going to help, because `tostring` only gets to see the number **after** the jq parser has read the input.

The jq maintainers are well-aware of this issue and indeed there is a "pull request" which addresses it:
https://github.com/stedolan/jq/pull/1752

If you wish to use an officially released version of jq, then the only available "workaround" will be to change the number in the JSON source to a string.  You might wish to use the "bigint" library for handling "bigint" strings - https://github.com/joelpurra/jq-bigint

## UPDATES

As of Oct 22, 2019, the version of jq at "master" preserves the precision of numbers that are read, and `tostring` can be used on such numbers without loss of precision, e.g.

```
$ jq tostring
123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789
"123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789"
```

You might alternatively wish to use gojq, the Go implementation of jq.